# Equivalent of LastCall.IgnoreArguments in EasyMock

Tags: java, mocking, rhino-mocks, easymock

I have used Rhino.Mocks extensively currently writing some tests in Java using EasyMocks. However I was unable to pull out a LastCall.IgnoreArguments() Rhino.Mocks equivalent in EasyMocks.

How do I use Easy Mocks to return a value irrespective of the arguments in the method.

For example:

```
public interface ISoothSayer {

   String SaySomethingSweet(String sweetMsg);
}
```

how do I mock this interface to return "Hell Oh World" irrespective of the argument, sweetMsg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use isA, like below (mock is a ISoothSayer mock):

```
expect(mock.SaySomethingSweet(isA(String.class))).andReturn("Hell Oh World");
```